# Jansy Bootstrap Off-Canvas Menu Not Closing on Single Click

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I am using the Jansy Bootstrap Off-Canvas Menu in my Angular App, which is using UI-Router. Additionally, I have changed some of the styling to extend the responsive style of the menu for small and larger devices. On Desktop the menu should be along the left side without the toggle button and animate away, as the browser gets smaller. I have successfully done this with the exception of not being able to close the menu and have the body slide back to the left when on a smaller device. It only works if I click twice as opposed to only clicking once.

```css
body {
  margin: 60px 0px 0px 250px;
}
.navmenu-fixed-left {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #202020;
  transition: left .5s;
}
.navmenu > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.navmenu > ul > li {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
.navmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #eee;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.navmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navmenu > ul > li:hover,
.active {
  background: #000;
}
.navmenu > ul > li > a > i {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.navbar {
  left: 250px;
  transition: left .3s;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}
.navbar {
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  html,
  body {
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  .navmenu-fixed-left {
    left: -250px;
    margin-top: -60px;
  }
  .navbar {
    left: 0px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav id="myNavmenu" class="navmenu navmenu-inverse navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="overview">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="transactions"><i class="fa fa-history" aria-hidden="true"></i> Chickens</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="teams"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cows</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="members"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>Pigs</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="cards"><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sheep</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="trends"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Dogs</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <p class="navbar-brand dynamictitle"><i class="fa fa-bars navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$title}}</p>

</div>
<!--Main Content included from different view -->
<!--Navbar include-->
<div ui-view="navBar"></div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <p>Main Content Here.....</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems to work as expected: please post any additional code (or info) that recreates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own issue. Here is how I did it: 
I added a controller to my page to remove the inline style that gets added to the body, then changed the css by removing any styling from body or html.

```js
angular.module('myApp').controller('navCtrl', function () {
$('body').removeAttr("style");
});
```

```css
/*html, body{margin:60px 0px 0px 250px;}*/
.main {margin:60px 0px 0px 250px;}

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
/*html, body{margin:30px 0px 0px 0px; height: 100% !important;}*/
.main{margin:60px 0px 0px 0px;}
```